# Matching with arrays results segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays

from this code,

```
node[4] = {5,3,2,6};  
neighbor[4] = {4,7,8,9};
```

I have to find,

- `node[0]` and `node[1]` has any common values from `neighbor[0-3]`
- or `node[1]` and `node[2]` has any common values from `neighbor[0-3]`
- or `node[2]` and node[3] has any common values from `neighbor[0-3]`

if any one satisfies print element found else not...
I have tried this code, but there is error states segmentation fault .

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int node[4] = {5,3,2,6};
    int neighbor[4] = {4,3,2,9};
    int sub,i,flag=0,k=0;

    for (k=0;k<3;k++){
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (node[k]==neighbor[i])
                flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag==1)
        sub=k+1;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (node[sub]==neighbor[i])
            flag=2;
        break;
    }
    if (flag==2)
        printf("Element not found\n");
    else
        printf("Element  found\n");
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to break out of *both* loops? And conditionally? You’re going to need some braces, I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int node[4] = {5,3,2,6};
    int neighbor[4] = {4,3,2,9};
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;

    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<4; j++) {
            if (node[i]==neighbor[j]) {
                for (k=0; k<4; k++) {
                    if (node[i+1]==neighbor[k]) {
                        printf("Element found: %d %d\n", node[i], node[i+1]);
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Element not found\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: node[4] = {5,3,2,6};neighbor[4] = {4,3,2,9}; results element found which is correct but when i change the values as node[4] = {5,3,2,6};neighbor[4] = {4,8,2,9} still it shows element found ..node{2} alone matches with neighbor {4,8,2,9}

Comment: Thanks. Upon closer inspection it appears the algorithm is also incorrect (what if elements 0, 2, and 3 match)?  I've updated my code above to use a different algorithm.

Comment: node[x] and node[x+1] values has to match with neighbor node.if both matches print output as element found else not.
but in your code, if i have input as  node[4] = {5,3,2,6};neighbor[4] = {4,3,2,9}, here node[1] and node[2]  matches with neighbor but output results element not found

Comment: Updated answer again to contain full solution.

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing out of bounds of the array.

```
sub=k+1;
```

With this, you set k to 4 and then in the subsequent loop, you access `node[sub]`. Only 0 to 3 are valid indexes for `node`.

---

Accessing out of bounds memory is **undefined behaviour**. You probably meant to break out of both loops.

```
    for (k=0;k<3;k++){
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (node[k]==neighbor[i])
            {
              flag=1;
              break;
            }
            if (flag == 1) break;
        }
    }

    if (flag==1) {
       sub=k+1;
       for (i = 0; i < 4 && sub < 4; i++) 
       {
            if (node[sub]==neighbor[i]) 
            {
              flag=2;
              break;
            }
      }
   }
```

Note the condition in the for loop: `sub < 4` to ensure you don't access out of bounds.

---

```
#include<stdio.h>

int present(int x, int y, int N[])
{
  int i, c=0;
  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
      if(N[i]==x) c++;
      if(N[i]==y) c++;
  }
  if (c==2) return 1;
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int node[4] = {5,3,2,6};
    int neighbor[4] = {4,8,2,9};
    int sub,i,flag=0,k=0;

    for (k=0;k<3;k++){
        if (present(node[k], node[k+1], neighbor)) {
           flag = 1;
           printf("Element found");
           break;
        }
    }
    if(flag == 0) 
       printf("Element not found");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: node[4] = {5,3,2,6};neighbor[4] = {4,3,2,9}; results element found which is correct but when i change the values as node[4] = {5,3,2,6};neighbor[4] = {4,8,2,9} still it shows element found ..node{2} alone matches with neighbor {4,8,2,9}

Comment: I am not sure what your program supposed to do. Can you explain what you aim to achieve? What do you mean by *common value*?

Comment: in this code, node[x] and node[x+1] values has to match with neighbor node.if both matches print output as element found else not.
but if i have input as  node[4] = {5,3,2,6};neighbor[4] = {4,8,2,9}, here node{2} alone matches with neighbor but output results element found

Comment: `sub = k + 1` is no issue, because the maximum value of `k` at this point will be `2` (see the `for()`; so should be fine). Also, rather than checking for `flag == 1` inside the loops, I'd just add it to the condition for the outer loop.

Comment: @Mario I believe the entire for loop should be inside the `if(flag==1)`. So `sub` will be set before accessing `node` even if sub is less than 4.

Comment: @Reshmy Can you explain `node[x] and node[x+1] values has to match with neighbor node`? Both node[x] and node[x+1] should be in the neibhbor array?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. You don't need the condition in the loop, as it breaks free anyway.

Comment: @Reshmy As per your clarification, I updated my answer. Check if it works.

Answer (score 1):

`sub` is undefined/not set, in case `flag` is never set to `1`, so you're essentially using an uninitialized value as your index, resulting in your program reading from wherever it points to.